Top bar problem
When I click on the top bar on the left where I have icons (desktop) they start to go down for a while and then the gnome shell itself starts to lag. Does anyone know how to fix it?
Ubuntu 24.04

For how long does the shell lag?  For a short period of time, until the shell is restarted, or until the system is restarted?
